# How Can i encode jwt Data With rsa with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have to encode the data with python rsa with public key but i have isse with it

this is the code

```
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
def rsa_long_encrypt(key_,msg, length=50):
    key = RSA.importKey(key_)
    cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(key)
    res = []
    for i in range(0, len(msg), length):
        msg_to_en = msg[i:i+length]
        ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(msg_to_en)
        res.append(ciphertext)
    
    return "".join(res)


if __name__ == "__main__":
     message = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c'
    enres = rsa_long_encrypt(key,message, 20)
    print(enres)
```

even i try this thing with php and it's work and it encrypt the data

i'm intersting in jwt format data to be encode with rsa

result with php

```
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
```

with python code i get this error message

```
db = lHash + ps + b'\x01' + _copy_bytes(None, None, message)
```

TypeError: can't concat str to bytes

Comment: you dont return anything ... so print(enres) probably just says None ...

Comment: it return see the code agian

Comment: what is _copy_bytes? what is ps? ... one of these is a str and its expecting bytes (you can always use str.encode() to convert str to bytes